# jQuery Pop up doesnt get open on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have implemented a jquery pop up

as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[id$=btnclick]").click(function () {
                if ($("#content").html() != "") {
                    AlertDialog($("#content").html());
                }
            });
        });

        function AlertDialog(msg) {
            $.modaldialog.success(msg, {
                width: 400,
                height: 100
            });
        }
//        $(document).ready(function () {
//            if ($("#content").html() != "") {
//                AlertDialog($("#content").html());
//            }
//        });
    </script>

<asp:Button ID="btnclick" runat="server" Text="click me"   />
```

on document.getready the popup open correctly
but on click the pop up doesn't open.Thanks for assistance

Comment: Do you see an error in your JavaScript console? Have you used console.log at certain places? (Inside the click handler)?

Comment: I guess it is certainly not finding any element with the ID "btnclick" so can you show us some of your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you place the click on an input, inputs make post back, probably you need to prevent that using the `e.preventDefault();` as:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[id$=btnclick]").click(function (e) 
        {
            if ($("#content").html() != "") {
                // here prevent from post back
                e.preventDefault();

                AlertDialog($("#content").html());
            }
        });
    });
```

And a test: http://jsfiddle.net/TwFX5/2/

Comment: Sir it doesn't prevent from post back

Answer (score 0):

In your attribute selector:

```
$("input[id$=btnclick]")
```

You'r missing the inner quotes:

```
$("input[id$='btnclick']")
             ^        ^
```

---

Your JavaScript is just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pf9PW/1/, [with](http://jsfiddle.net/pf9PW/) or without the inner quotes (although) you *should* have them.

Comment: You have right that have forget them, but its work even with out them.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/pf9PW/2/ why I am say that is need to prevent post back.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing that I would say that if you have an id, use it directly and don't look for an id in all inputs. It just increases the over-head for the browser. So instead of using

```
$("input[id$=btnclick]").click(function () {
    if ($("#content").html() != "") {
        AlertDialog($("#content").html());
    }
});
```

Use

```
$("#btnclick").click(function () {
    if ($("#content").html() != "") {
        AlertDialog($("#content").html());
    }
});
```

And for your problem it can not be resolved unless we see the whole picture. And try to avoid making the same call more then once in a function. Instead of doing

```
if ($("#content").html() != "") {
    AlertDialog($("#content").html());
}
```

Do

```
var markup = $("#content").html();
if (markup != "") {
    AlertDialog(markup);
}
```

Optimized code is the key to secure and faster applications.

Comment: sir first thing $("input[id$=btnclick]") i have used this because i am using a asp.net button. As you might know it is a server side control it changes it id on runtime. $("#btnclick") if i use this it won't run the code.

Comment: Secondly, i have pasted the button html and the code that i am trying to run on it. so i am sorry if still the picture is not clear to you. You need extra study to deal with my problem.